# How to develop a win application using MVC pattern

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

following a MVC pattern how can i develop a windows application with c#. is there any site from where i can have the knowledge to build the flow in my win application which follow the MVC pattern. basically i need to write the code in such a way when other developer read my code then they will understand that i have followed the MVC patter in my coding flow. i don't know MVC style coding so please help me with adequate information. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC/MVP framework for .NET WinForms applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536888/mvc-mvp-framework-for-net-winforms-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Gang of four book :
http://www.exciton.cs.rice.edu/JavaResources/DesignPatterns/book/hires/chap1fso.htm#sec1-2